# Displaying columns in Sales Order Grid

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, order-grid

I have the following code to show some extra columns in the sales order grid. It correctly shows the columns and data, but when I try to click an order it says "No order exists".

I wondered if anyone can spot where I might be going wrong?

This code is in: /app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('sales_order_grid');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve collection class
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getCollectionClass()
    {
        return 'sales/order_grid_collection';
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

        $collection->getSelect()->join(array('billing'=>'sales_flat_order_address'),'main_table.entity_id=billing.parent_id and billing.address_type="billing"',array('*'));

        $collection->getSelect()->join(array('shipping'=>'sales_flat_order_address'),'main_table.entity_id=shipping.parent_id and shipping.address_type="shipping"',array('shipping.company as  shipping_company'));



        $this->setCollection($collection);

        parent::_prepareCollection();
        return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

        $this->addColumn('real_order_id', array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order #'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'index' => 'increment_id',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order Date'),
            'index' => 'created_at',
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'width' => '100px',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Billing Name'),
            'index' => 'billing_name',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('company', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Billing Company'),
            'index' => 'company',
            'filter_index' => 'billing.company',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('shipping_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Name'),
            'index' => 'shipping_name',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('shipping_company', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Company'),
            'index' => 'shipping_company',
            'filter_index' => 'shipping.company',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Grand Total'),
            'index' => 'grand_total',
            'type'  => 'currency',
            'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('status', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status'),
            'index' => 'status',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'width' => '70px',
            'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
        ));

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
            $this->addColumn('action',
                array(
                    'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Action'),
                    'width'     => '50px',
                    'type'      => 'action',
                    'getter'     => 'getId',
                    'actions'   => array(
                        array(
                            'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('View'),
                            'url'     => array('base'=>'*/sales_order/view'),
                            'field'   => 'order_id',
                            'data-column' => 'action',
                        )
                    ),
                    'filter'    => false,
                    'sortable'  => false,
                    'index'     => 'stores',
                    'is_system' => true,
                ));
        }
        //$this->addRssList('rss/order/new', Mage::helper('sales')->__('New Order RSS'));

        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel XML'));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('order_ids');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(false);

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/cancel')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('cancel_order', array(
                'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Cancel'),
                'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massCancel'),
            ));
        }

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/hold')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('hold_order', array(
                'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Hold'),
                'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massHold'),
            ));
        }

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/unhold')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('unhold_order', array(
                'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Unhold'),
                'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massUnhold'),
            ));
        }

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfinvoices_order', array(
            'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Invoices'),
            'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfinvoices'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfshipments_order', array(
            'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Packingslips'),
            'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfshipments'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfcreditmemos_order', array(
            'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Credit Memos'),
            'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfcreditmemos'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfdocs_order', array(
            'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print All'),
            'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfdocs'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('print_shipping_label', array(
            'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Shipping Labels'),
            'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order_shipment/massPrintShippingLabel'),
        ));

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
            return $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $row->getId()));
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f2a857c980c2edb8c435219ba37e7913) shows the changes from my 1.9ish Grid.php

```
--- Grid.php    2015-10-20 15:37:24.000000000 +0100
+++ Delete.php  2016-07-11 13:12:38.000000000 +0100
@@ -57,8 +57,17 @@
     protected function _prepareCollection()
     {
         $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
+
+        $collection->getSelect()->join(array('billing'=>'sales_flat_order_address'),'main_table.entity_id=billing.parent_id and billing.address_type="billing"',array('*'));
+
+        $collection->getSelect()->join(array('shipping'=>'sales_flat_order_address'),'main_table.entity_id=shipping.parent_id and shipping.address_type="shipping"',array('shipping.company as  shipping_company'));
+
+
+
         $this->setCollection($collection);
-        return parent::_prepareCollection();
+
+        parent::_prepareCollection();
+        return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
     }

     protected function _prepareColumns()
@@ -71,42 +80,37 @@
             'index' => 'increment_id',
         ));

-        if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
-            $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
-                'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased From (Store)'),
-                'index'     => 'store_id',
-                'type'      => 'store',
-                'store_view'=> true,
-                'display_deleted' => true,
-            ));
-        }
-
         $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
-            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
+            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order Date'),
             'index' => 'created_at',
             'type' => 'datetime',
             'width' => '100px',
         ));

         $this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
-            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
+            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Billing Name'),
             'index' => 'billing_name',
         ));

+        $this->addColumn('company', array(
+            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Billing Company'),
+            'index' => 'company',
+            'filter_index' => 'billing.company',
+        ));
+
         $this->addColumn('shipping_name', array(
-            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ship to Name'),
+            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Name'),
             'index' => 'shipping_name',
         ));

-        $this->addColumn('base_grand_total', array(
-            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Base)'),
-            'index' => 'base_grand_total',
-            'type'  => 'currency',
-            'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
+        $this->addColumn('shipping_company', array(
+            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Company'),
+            'index' => 'shipping_company',
+            'filter_index' => 'shipping.company',
         ));

         $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
-            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Purchased)'),
+            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Grand Total'),
             'index' => 'grand_total',
             'type'  => 'currency',
             'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
@@ -141,7 +145,7 @@
                     'is_system' => true,
             ));
         }
-        $this->addRssList('rss/order/new', Mage::helper('sales')->__('New Order RSS'));
+        //$this->addRssList('rss/order/new', Mage::helper('sales')->__('New Order RSS'));

         $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
         $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel XML'));
```

The bit that's weird is why you're calling `prepareCollectin` twice but it doesn't look like that would affect the view link. You might want to post the full diff of what you changed, against your base version of magento, and also what is getting generated as the view url for each row.

Comment: Hi Richard. Thanks for sharing. I left the default Grid.php alone and replicated in my local folder as above.

Comment: A bump to see if anyone else has any thoughts on this one? Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Got this working finally with the following code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Adminhtml
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2014 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

/**
 * Adminhtml sales orders grid
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Adminhtml
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('sales_order_grid');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve collection class
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getCollectionClass()
    {
        return 'sales/order_grid_collection';
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

        $collection->getSelect()->join(array('billing'=>'sales_flat_order_address'),'main_table.entity_id=billing.parent_id and billing.address_type="billing"',array('billing.company as billing_company'));

        $collection->getSelect()->join(array('shipping'=>'sales_flat_order_address'),'main_table.entity_id=shipping.parent_id and shipping.address_type="shipping"',array('shipping.company as shipping_company'));

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

        $this->addColumn('real_order_id', array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order #'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'index' => 'increment_id',
        ));

        if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased From (Store)'),
                'index'     => 'store_id',
                'type'      => 'store',
                'store_view'=> true,
                'display_deleted' => true,
            ));
        }

        $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
            'index' => 'created_at',
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'width' => '100px',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
            'index' => 'billing_name',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('company', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Billing Company'),
            'index' => 'billing_company',
            'filter_index' => 'billing.company',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('shipping_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ship to Name'),
            'index' => 'shipping_name',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('shipping_company', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Company'),
            'index' => 'shipping_company',
            'filter_index' => 'shipping.company',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('base_grand_total', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Base)'),
            'index' => 'base_grand_total',
            'type'  => 'currency',
            'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Purchased)'),
            'index' => 'grand_total',
            'type'  => 'currency',
            'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('status', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status'),
            'index' => 'status',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'width' => '70px',
            'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
        ));

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
            $this->addColumn('action',
                array(
                    'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Action'),
                    'width'     => '50px',
                    'type'      => 'action',
                    'getter'     => 'getId',
                    'actions'   => array(
                        array(
                            'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('View'),
                            'url'     => array('base'=>'*/sales_order/view'),
                            'field'   => 'order_id',
                            'data-column' => 'action',
                        )
                    ),
                    'filter'    => false,
                    'sortable'  => false,
                    'index'     => 'stores',
                    'is_system' => true,
                ));
        }
        $this->addRssList('rss/order/new', Mage::helper('sales')->__('New Order RSS'));

        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel XML'));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('order_ids');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(false);

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/cancel')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('cancel_order', array(
                'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Cancel'),
                'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massCancel'),
            ));
        }

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/hold')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('hold_order', array(
                'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Hold'),
                'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massHold'),
            ));
        }

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/unhold')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('unhold_order', array(
                'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Unhold'),
                'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massUnhold'),
            ));
        }

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfinvoices_order', array(
            'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Invoices'),
            'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfinvoices'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfshipments_order', array(
            'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Packingslips'),
            'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfshipments'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfcreditmemos_order', array(
            'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Credit Memos'),
            'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfcreditmemos'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfdocs_order', array(
            'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print All'),
            'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfdocs'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('print_shipping_label', array(
            'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Shipping Labels'),
            'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order_shipment/massPrintShippingLabel'),
        ));

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
            return $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $row->getId()));
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
    }

}
```